# Plotly indicators number rounding

Tags: python, plotly, dashboard, plotly-python

When using Plotly (in python) with an indicator if the number is relatively big the number is rounded. How to avoid this (or at least control it)?

```py
fig_ind_abs = go.Figure(go.Indicator(
        mode="number+delta",
        value=5222,
        delta={'position': "top", 'reference': 5218}))
```

will show the following indicator
[image: Result]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to format the indicator number. You should add `{'valueformat':'f'}` to your code wherever you need float values.[`Reference`](https://plotly.com/python/reference/indicator/#indicator-number)

Full list of available customizations [`d3 format api`](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Formatting.md#d3_format)

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
go.Figure(go.Indicator(
        mode="number+delta",
        value=5222,
        delta={'position': "top", 'reference': 5218, 'valueformat':'f'},
        number = {'valueformat':'f'}
))
```

[image]

Comment: And how to specify this for the delta (it is still 0)

Comment: nvm i found just add ```'valueformat': 'f'``` in the delta dict thanks

Comment: be careful with decimals while using `f`. You can use `g` if you need decimals but as expected it is prone to standard floating point issue in CS.